# Is Ubuntu an open source software?

Tags: open-source

Is Ubuntu an open source software (OSS)?

Comment: Related question on UNIX.SE: [What makes Ubuntu **not** totally Free Software?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1856/what-makes-ubuntu-not-totally-free-software)

Comment: Ubuntu is not open source. Its a project that uses many FOSS projects but Ubuntus source code is not open to anyone. Think of it like a burger from your favorite shop. You know what it has. But you never know how such things were combined or what was added in the process because you can never see how its made or you yourself will never be able to make it. Simply because the source code for Ubuntu is nowhere near OPEN.

Comment: the link http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop says Ubuntu is open source. But note that anything Open Source means its SOURCE is open! True that ubuntu is a combination of large amount of free and open source software but that DOES NOT make Ubuntu open source because even though those software are open source, the source code for UBUNTU is no where to be found!

Comment: And This question is not a duplicate question. The linked question is about some legal aspect. This is a different question. Clearly there is something fishy going on this forum.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a simple question at all.

As well as Debian’s one, official repository of Ubuntu includes free (mostly) and some non-free software in different *sections*, but their names are not so clear: `main` and `universe` consist of free packages, `restricted` and `multiverse` –  of non-free. Some of packages in the latter two could be really necessary to use you PC (like some firmwares and some drivers), but the rest are not.

Moreover, Ubuntu makes installing non-free software easy enough to be installed *accidentely* without realizing what did you install.

If you are concerned about non-free software on your PC, you might use `aptitude` to find out whether anything non-free is installed:

```
$ aptitude search '?installed (?section(restricted) | ?section(multiverse))'
```

or install a small utility `vrms`, and ask it:

```
$ vrms
```

If you are conserned a lot about using only free software, you might consider installing a [Trisquel GNU/Linux](http://trisquel.info/), which is basically *completely* free Ubuntu.

As for the term ‘open source’, if you just use it as a synonym to ‘free / libre’, see all the above. But if you cares about Open Source Initiative opinion and want to follow it strictly (there are actually few who do it, but if), then even the `main` and `universe` sections of repository includes some software, which is *not* ‘open source’ according to OSI: OpenSSL is a most notable example. Yes, OpenSSL cannot be technically called ‘open source’ according to OSI (despite the http://openssl.org states the opposite), since [its license](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/License:OpenSSL) is basically conjunction of license of SSLeay and 4-clause BSD License, so it inherited obnoxious BSD advertising clause, which is not OSI-approved.

Comment: Could I use Ubuntu for any purpose for free? Like if a large company wants to use Ubuntu would they have to pay anything?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is!

> Ubuntu software is free. Always was, always will be. Free software gives everyone the freedom to use it however they want and share with whoever they like.

Refer [the Ubuntu philosophy](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/our-philosophy) for detailed information.

Comment: OSS ≠ Free. There is free software that's not open source (example: Adobe Flash Player).

Comment: @ToDo Adobe Flash Player is not a free / libre software, it is and always was proprietary.

Comment: Flash Player is free (you do not have to pay to use it) but not Open Source (as you said it is proprietary software).

Comment: @ToDo That’s not enough to call it [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html), as well as if sources are published that’s not enough to call some software ‘open source’. Both terms are very confusing. English language is notorious for lack of the adjective associated to freedom / liberty (while most languages have it). The word ‘libre’ (borrowed from French) might help to express the point clearly.

Comment: @ToDo Flash Player is *freeware*, not free software.

Comment: @muru _Gratis_ (adj.) might be better term for it.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov True - gratis v libre.

Comment: I think @ToDo's point is that this answer doesn't clearly answer the question. Because of the ambiguity between gratis/libre, saying "Ubuntu software is free" doesn't answer the question "Is Ubuntu open source?"

Comment: this answer is incorrect. You have mentionsed ubuntu is open source, but if so, where is it source code? Open Sourse means CODE IS OPEN!!! Where is the code for Ubuntu??